# Input string was not in a correct format error while saving data from GridView to database

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ado.net

I am trying to store my gridview into a database but I can't seem to do it. How should I solve it?

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in gv_CartView.Rows)
{
    int quantity = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[2].Text);
    Session["Quantity"] = quantity;

    decimal TotalPrice = Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells[4].Text);
    Session["TotalPrice"] = TotalPrice;

    string queryStr = "INSERT into Cart (prod_Id,prod_Name,qty,prod_Price,total_Amt)"
    + "values (@ItemID,@Product_Name,@Quantity,@Product_Price,@TotalPrice)";
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(_connStr);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(queryStr, conn);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ItemID", row.Cells[0].Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Product_Name", row.Cells[1].Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantity", Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[2].Text));
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Product_Price", Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells[3].Text));
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TotalPrice", Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells[4].Text));

    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
}
```

I get this error:

> "Input string was not in a correct format"

from the following lines and I have changed the codes many times but it still does not work.

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantity", Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[2].Text));
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Product_Price", Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells[3].Text));
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TotalPrice", Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells[4].Text));
```

Comment: The error states that one of the values in your cell is not convertible to integer or decimal.

Comment: Don't use `Convert`, it's just a call to `int.Parse` or `decimal.Parse` that doesn't allow you to specify additional parameters like CultureInfo.

Comment: The error comes from the attempt to *parse* the cell text. Most likely the user entered a decimal value with a separator used in one locale while the *web app* runs on a different locale. Eg, entered `1,5` when the web app is configured for `en-US`.